# ReactJS and Laravel, nested route is not working. It bring me to the same page

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router

I'm developing a blog using Laravel 7 and ReactJS. I have a /blog page and for each blog I have a post. The post should be displayed in /blog/post/1 type, but this routing is not working: it returns to the /blog page. I'm not sure if the problem is with react routing or Laravel routing.

My route in web.php, Laravel:

```
Route::view('/{path?}', 'react');
```

My route in App.js file, ReactJS :

```
<Router> 
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
    <Route path="/blog/post/:id" component={Post} />
    <Route path="*" component={notfound} />
</Switch> 
</Router>
```

Link on /blog page to view a post with id 12

```
<Link to="/blog/post/12">React More</Link>
```

When I click the above link it brings me again to /blog page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routes are prioritised by order. So the order you have them in matters.
You could do:

```
<Router> 
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/blog/post/:id" component={Post} />
    <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
    <Route path="*" component={notfound} />
</Switch> 
</Router>
```

Or by using the 'exact' keyword like you did for the / route, so it has to be an exact match.

```
<Router> 
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/blog" component={Blog} />
    <Route path="/blog/post/:id" component={Post} />
    <Route path="*" component={notfound} />
</Switch> 
</Router>
```

Comment: James, thanks a lot for your helpful answer. I was thinking the Switch treat "/blog" and "/blog/post/:id" differently. The problem solved.